# how to load a modal window at the user's current scroll location

Tags: modal-dialog

At [this page](http://gm.insightcomdes.com.au/), at bottom right, there is a YouTube play button that when clicked opens a modal window, but the modal window appears at the top of the browser window, so the user has to scroll upwards.

```
<img src="http://gm.insightcomdes.com.au/wp-content/themes/wtc%2029.3.18/images/icons/video-play.png" width="" height="" alt="play video" class="aligncenter" id="toggle">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#toggle').click(function(){
        jQuery('#video').appendTo('body');
        jQuery('#video').addClass('active');
        jQuery(window).scrollTo(jQuery('#top').scrollTo());
    });
    jQuery('#close').click(function(){
        jQuery('#video').removeClass('active');
    });              
});

<div class="mfp-container active" id="video">
    <div class="mfp-content">
         <p align="right"><img src="http://gm.insightcomdes.com.au/wp-content/themes/wtc%2029.3.18/images/icons/close.png" alt="close video" width="20" height="20" id="close"></p>
         <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ut6UYwbt6Xk" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>            
     </div>
</div>

<style>
.mfp-container {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 8px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: none;
    z-index: 999999999;
}
.mfp-container.active {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
</style>
```

Obviously the `.mfp-container` CSS rule sets a top and left of 0.

How can I set the `.mfp-container` to display at the current user's location within the page without hard-coding values, as this video widget may be anywhere on the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to be using CSS `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`.  That will always keep the modal in a fixed position on the screen instead of an absolute position relative to some other element.

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
window.onload = function() {
  var scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  $('#modal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
    .css({
      'top': scrollPos + 'px',
      'margin-top': 0
    });
}
```